# XOR для поиска лишнего элемента

Tags: алгоритм

Всем привет. Наткнулся на алгоритм поиска лишнего элемента в массиве, при том что все остальные элементы идут попарно с повторами, типа {3,3,2,2,1} - лишняя единица. Так вот алгоритм решения "найти лишний элемент" это проXORить весь массив по порядку и результат будет последнее число. Операция XOR дает true когда два бита разные. Теперь собственно вопрос: объясните, каким образом этот алгоритм дает правильный ответ? То есть каков принцип, почему в итоге остается именно лишнее число, в каком месте массива оно бы не находилось

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё просто.

Для начала, операция `xor` определена не только на отдельных битах, но и на числах: для получения результата выполняется побитный xor операндов.

Нам понадобятся следующие свойства операции `xor`:

1. Коммутативность: `p xor q == q xor p`.
2. Вариант антисимметричности: `p xor p == 0`
3. Нейтральный элемент: `p xor 0 == p`.

Эти свойства легко проверить побитно, для чисел они выполняются как следствие побитной проверки.

Рассмотрим выражение

```
p[0] xor p[1] xor ... xor p[n-1].
```

Согласно 1, можно переставлять элементы последовательности, не меняя при этом результат. Мысленно переставим тогда элементы так, чтобы пары одинаковых шли подряд:

```
a xor a xor b xor b xor c xor c xor ... xor z
```

Но

```
a xor a == 0
a xor a xor b xor b = 0 xor b xor b = b xor b = 0
```

и так далее. Мы видим, что в конце останется просто элемент без пары.

Comment: обалдеть как все просто, но самому до такого додуматься крайне сложно =( Спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: @Kirill Bazarov: пожалуйста!